# How to call different associated resource variables in their controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner learning Ruby on Rails.  Apologies if this question is very obvious...

I have two resources:

books and book_pages

A book has several pages and I have set up the belongs_to and has_many associations within the models.  In the controller for book pages, how do I create a new book_page under this association?  I currently have:

```
class BookPagesController < ApplicationController
...

def new
  @book_page = BookPage.new

   end
end

...
```

Also, how would I need to set up the corresponding view to create a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you would need to use a code like this:

```
book = Book.find(book_id)
book.book_pages.create(page_number: 1, footnote: "yey")
```

But note that you need to have the book id somehow in your request.

I strongly advise you to stop muddling through and read the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), because rails uses convention over configuration which can be very confusing if you are not up to read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to test things on `rails console`, it's really useful for debugging. ActiveRecord::Base models can be initialized with associations like this:

```
Book.create(
  title: "TITLE",
  book_pages: [
    { text: "blabllblablalblab", number: 1) },
    { text: "kasdhfkjahwkqjrgs", number: 2) }
    # ....
  ]
)
```

@fotanus answer is equally valid. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html